# No module named "xyz" in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path

I am new to python so this could be a wrong question to ask .I have installed python 3.4 and is trying to convert an old project of python 2.2 to python 3.

I have the pythonpath as "C:\ABC;C:\XY"

I do have the following structure :
[image: structure]

In the install.py, there is code to import MiscUtils.Utils1.py:

```
from MiscUtils import Utils1
```

But in the Utils1.py , another code is there to import Utils2.py:

```
from UserUtils import Utils2
```

When I execute the install.py, I am getting the following error:

```
"No module named Utils2"
```

I tried many a things but its not working. If I put in the Utils1.py the following:

```
from .UserUtils import Utils2
```

I am getting `"No Module named MiscUtils.UserUtils"`

How can I import all these modules correctly
?

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in the `MiscUtils` and `UserUtils` directories?

Comment: Since you did not get `No module named 'UserUtils'`, `UserUtils` must have been imported correctly, as the `from` module has to be imported first.  (Try `from xyz import abc` and python complains about xyz, not abc.)  My first guess is that `Utils2` is not spelled exactly that way in both the code and the directory, but I am not sitting at your screen.